# SQL install fail on AWS CentOS

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services, centos

I get the following error but when I try and install the missing dependencies then it either says its already install (openssl) or that such package doesn't exist.

here are the step that I'm following - https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-microsoft-sql-server-ms-sql-rhel-centos-ubuntu-evaluation-version.html

What should I do to get past this error?

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: repo.us.bigstepcloud.com
 * updates: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mssql-server.x86_64 0:14.0.900.75-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1:1.0.1 for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: numactl-libs for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gdb for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsss_nss_idmap for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdb.x86_64 0:7.2-92.el6 will be installed
---> Package libsss_nss_idmap.x86_64 0:1.13.3-57.el6_9 will be installed
---> Package mssql-server.x86_64 0:14.0.900.75-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1:1.0.1 for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: numactl-libs for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server)
           Requires: numactl-libs
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server)
           Requires: openssl >= 1:1.0.1
           Installed: openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
               openssl = 1.0.1e-57.el6
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.900.75-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to install a package that has been built for RHEL7, on a CentOS6 server. MsSql-server is only available for RHEL7.